# Scalar product definied by matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Check that bilinear form given as matrix for basic base  $$
>      \quad 
>          \begin{pmatrix}
>          0 & 1 & 0\\
>          1 & 4 & 0\\
>          0 & 0 & 2
>          \end{pmatrix}
>      \quad $$
>
> is scalar product $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Idea:
I have nontechnical solution, but I don't know why it is right.

1. Check the symmetry of matrix.
2. Check Sylvester's criterion for positive-definite

I need explain why its work? Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matrix does not define a scalar product. Recall that given a scalar product $\langle \,\cdot \, , \, \cdot \, \rangle$  we have that $\langle v,v \rangle=0$ if, and only if, $v=0$. But in the case of the scalar product defined by its matrix we have
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 0\\
   1 & 4 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 \\ 0 \\ 0
   \end{pmatrix}
&=0
\end{align}